# why i am getting error 'ObjectPoolingManager.Instance' is inaccessible due to its protection level?

Tags: c#

My player script

> Error CS0122: 'ObjectPoolingManager.Instance' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Code:

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
    {
        ObjectPoolingManager.Instance.GetBullet ();

        GameObject bulletObject = Instantiate (bulletPrefab);
        bulletObject.transform.position = playerCamera.transform.position + playerCamera.transform.forward;
        bulletObject.transform.forward = playerCamera.transform.forward;
    }
}
```

Comment: please make sure that `Instance` is public

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your class declaration, you must have made it
`Internal class ObjectPoolingManager()`
You can make it accessible by changing it to
`Public class ObjectPoolingManager()`